# Why the client does not work in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Unable to connect to server and bring information

It does not show any error

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://shop76.ir/api/");
            var products = await client.GetAsync("products/");
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(products.ToString()))
            {
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
                {
                    var productList = serializer.Deserialize<List<ProductModel>>(jsonReader);
                    return productList;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error it shows?

Comment: have you verified connectivity to your server?  Have you done any basic network troubleshooting?